# how to exclude unnecessary entity in clean architecture domain project

Tags: entity-framework, clean-architecture

My db-context in the infrastructure project has many tables that I am not interested in my application. Other applications may need them but my application does not. If I remove them from my domain project the build will fail. Same question regarding unused properties. Please go easy on me... I'm new in here :)

Comment: Can you add an example of what you have tried? When working with existing databases where you want a partial representation I highly recommend employing manual configuration either using OnModelCreating, or better, `EntityTypeConfiguration` to map your desired entity to the DB rather than trying to use a designer/EDMX. Obviously if you are inserting rows you need to ensure all non-null-able properties are mapped.

Comment: Forget about inserts, I've got a code-first DBContext that supports several different clean-architecture applications. Not all of those applications need every table defined in the context. Therefore, each application MUST have an entity class for all tables, even the ones that it doesn't care about. Otherwise the build fails... not sure an example adds anything here as I've been clear as day. Maybe this is an engineering question? If so, sorry.

Comment: Then what exactly is your question? How you can define 1 DbContext for several applications, but not burden those applications with knowledge about every table and property?? Simple, don't *use* 1 single DbContext... Defining purpose-built DbContexts and entity definitions is simple. Smaller DbContexts initialize faster, and keep your domain interface to strictly the tables and columns that application needs rather than confusing future development with a lot of unnecessary unrelated fluff. Even within single large applications I will define multiple bounded DbContexts.